# subsetting by two conditions (True & False) evaluating to (True)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2':[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df[(df['col1'] == 1) | (df['col1'] == df['col1'].max()) & (df['col1'] > 2)]
```

Why doesn't this filter out the first row? Where col1 is less than 2?

I'm getting this:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     5
4     5     1
```

Expecting this:

```
   col1  col2
4     5     1
```

Comment: `a | b & c` is evaluated as `a | (b & c)`, not `(a | b) & c`.

Comment: So more  () is the answer?

Comment: Maybe? It's not clear what condition you actually want.

Comment: What do you actually want to do ?
It does filter out the 0th row and last row...

Comment: If you use `.eq(...)`/`.gt(...)` in place of `==`/`>` you won't have to use parentheses for `(x == y)`

Comment: `(a | b) & (c)` solved it. so in python (pandas?) does `&` always get evaluated first?

Answer (score 1):

Per the first comment (thanks chepner!), this solved it:

```
df[((df['col1'] == 1) | (df['col1'] == df['col1'].max())) & (df['col1'] > 2)]
```